# Spatial analysis separating size from location in mri

Tags: survival, spatial

Has anyone seen, done or understand how I can go about analyzing MRI datasets that have been registered to standard (MNI) space. What I´d like to do is analyze the effect on survival of lesion volume and lesion location, but the volume would necessarily be a function of the location. Also the voxels in the lesion location would not be independent.

Any ideas?